# Como definir uma cor de um Html.DisplayFor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helpers

Na minha aplicação eu tenho esse `Html Helpers`:

```
@Html.DropDownList("estado", new List<SelectListItem>{
    new SelectListItem {Text="Pago", Value="Pago"},
    new SelectListItem {Text="Pendente", Value="Pendente"}
    }, "Selecione o Estado:", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.estado, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

E aqui é onde eu exibo o item selecionado, ou seja, se foi escolhido **Pago** ou **Pendente**:

```
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.estado)
</td>
```

Portanto, gostaria que se fosse escolhido **Pago** ele ficasse escrito na *cor Verde*, caso **Pendente** que seja exibido na *cor vermelha*, como resolver esse problema?

Comment: Não é só um Javascript? tipo após a escolha alterar esse item para a cores desejadas?

Comment: Certo Virgilio, mas me dê um exemplo disso na prática, pois eu tentei de diversas formas e não deu!!